# Using Drawable in getView to make the ListView slow

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` that display `Drawable`s
 This is my code:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.main_advertisement_list_view_item, null);

                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            Log.d("view", holder.name+"");
            Log.d("string",getItem(position)+"");
            holder.name.setText(getItem(position).name);
            holder.icon.setImageResource(
                    categories_icons.getResourceId(position, -1));
            return convertView;
        }
```

How do I lazy load `Drawables`? I saw examples and samples, but for local drawables how can I achieve this since my code make the list view move slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public void setImageResource (int resId)

Since: API Level 1

Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.

This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, **which can cause a latency hiccup**. If that's a concern, consider using setImageDrawable

```
Drawable icon = _context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_1);
holder.icon.setImageDrawable(icon);
```